# VBA script for if-else

Tags: string, vba, if-statement, text

My column look like these for Column G:

**Column G**
Complete
Complete
In progress
Not Started
Complete

I need an If-Else script to convert all Complete values to 'Y', otherwise 'N'.
Can someone kindly help me?

Comment: Start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj692812(v=office.15).aspx and specificaly, the [If...Then...Else](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251599.aspx) documentation.

Comment: Could you clarify your question please ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You want a script or a formula? because this could be resolved as a formula like `=If(G1="Complete";"Y";"N")` pasted in a separate column, like column H for instance, and then dragged down to the end of your table. If you want a code, show us what you already have and then we can help you out

Comment: I am not familiar with VBA. SO I have not written any code for this. I need to automate this process using VBA. If a row value in Column G contains "Complete", How can that be changed to Y, otherwise "N" for all other cases.

Comment: If you are not familiar with VBA you need to become familiar with it. Stack Overflow is not a free coding service, and it is not a tutorial service.  It is designed to help programmers write their programs. What you want can be written using just the basics that can be learned in 2 or 3 hours by working through a tutorial. If you do so but then get stuck, edit this question to show your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

There are three basic elements of a VBA script which you need to learn.

1. Loop parameters (beginning --> end)
2. Action taken (what goes inside the loop)
3. Iteration (how do you move to the next record in the loop, avoiding an infinite loop)

   ```
   Sub MarkComplete()

   'Select first cell
   Range("G2").Select

   'Loop until no more values
   While ActiveCell.Value <> ""

       'Print appropriate value
       If ActiveCell.Value = "Complete" Then

           ActiveCell.Value = "Y"

       Else

           ActiveCell.Value = "N"

       End If

       'Move to next cell
       ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

   Wend

   End Sub
   ```